# when does the resize stop event called? (JQuery UI)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

hey every one.
i'd like to makes an object re-draggable after resize finishes but i do not know when does it finish.
what action calls the stop event?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`resizestop`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#event-stop) event, which is triggered at the end of a resize operation. You can tap into the event like this on initialization of the resizable object:

```
$("#resizable_div").resizable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        alert('stopped resizing');
    }
});
```

Or you can use `bind` to attach an event handler:

```
$("div").bind("resizestop", function(event, ui) {
    alert('stopped resizing');
});
```

Comment: i've tried the first option and for some reason it just never called that event. what does the user need to do so the event will be called?

Comment: @Ido_f: After the user releases the mouse, the event will be triggered.  I can set up a simple example if that'll help.