# gwt-query: resize event

Tags: java, gwt, resize, gwtquery

I was wondering if there is some kind of workaround for catching resize event completion on GWT-query. I've tryied to do it by $().resize() but it was no good. I've also thaught about catching mouseout event, but it doesn't work at leaving resize ui-grab icon.

Any idea? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(GQuery.window).resize(new Function(){
    public void f(){
      //Do something here when the window is resized
    }
}
```

Should work (resize event is sent on the window element only). If not, please open an issue here : http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/issues/list

Comment: Thank you very much jdramaix, but unfortunately it doesn't work on gwt-query. As far as I'm concerned that issue was already opened. I found a nasty workaround catching onmouseup querying elements with class ".ui-resizable" (something like that class in CSS), and apparently it worked.

Answer (score -1):

See into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880862/when-does-the-resize-stop-event-called-jquery-ui) thread. It seems to be a good approach to get what you want.

Comment: That question is about jQuery, this question is about GWT. Unfortunately not the same thing.

Comment: Agreed, however consider you can adapt jQuery code into gwt-query code, since gwt-query is a wrapper of jQuery for GWT.